# Add properties to an object after definition?

Tags: javascript

I know that in JavaScript you can add new properties to an instance of an existing type (like Date), but is it possible to add new properties to an instance of an anonymous type after it's been defined?

For example, say I have the following script:

```
var employee = {
    'Name': 'Scott',
    'Age': 32,
    'JavaScriptNewbie': true
};
```

Later on in my script I want to add a new property to this employee object (say, `Salary`). Is that possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would two people down vote this question? Did I make some Stackoverflow netiquette snafu?

Comment: No clue, but it should be pointed out that your syntax is incorrect, you need an `=` between `employee` and `{`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
employee.Salary = value;
```

Comment: Hah! That was remarkably easy and is straightforward and readable. Thanks a million. (I'll mark your answer as "The Answer" once Stackoverflow let's me... it says I need to wait another 8 minutes...)

Comment: The beauty of this answer is that it hits fine the SO-QA format. There is nothing more to say, just the code block. No stalling, no disposable intro-end texts. :)