# ionic 2: How I can adding a new item to an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

sample object:

```
        this.advData = {
                        'title': this.addAdvS2.value.title ,
                        'breadcrumb': this.suggestData.breadcrumb,
                        'price': this.addAdvS2.value.price,
                        'status': this.addAdvS2.value.status,
                        'province': this.addAdvS2.value.province,
                        'city': this.addAdvS2.value.city,
                        'images': this.addAdvS2.value.images
                    };
```

I want to add this item to "advData" object:

```
{'id': this.suggestData.id}
```

can I do this, without converting object to array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add properties to an anonymous JavaScript type after defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720207/add-properties-to-an-anonymous-javascript-type-after-defined)

Comment: @SurajRao thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it using the key:

```
this.advData['id'] = this.suggestData.id
```